# How can I make @unique directive work in datamodel.prisma?

Tags: graphql, prisma

So I just started using Prisma and I'm trying to add an email field in datamodel.prisma (which is a required String). It works all fine but I also want to give it @unique directive which doesn't really work.

I'm studying from a video course but my and instructor's files doesn't match, he has a datamodel.graphql file while mine is datamodel.prisma, thought maybe that was the reason and tried to manually change it to datamodel.graphql but after that I can't even use prisma deploy in terminal.

I expect not to be able to add users with same emails, it doesn't give me any error messages, but creating users with same emails is possible.

Would appreciate any help regarding this problem.

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: `type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
}`       here is my datamodel.prisma nothing really special about it.

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me, did you deploy your changes?

Comment: Of course. It says in the terminal that everything is fine but I can still add exactly the same string in the database in email field.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

Using Windows 10 and MariaDB (XAMPP). I added also the @unique directive - I already had some users in the table -  and still could add users with the same email address without any error messages in the console. However when I opened up the Docker Desktop app, I saw a buch of error messages, regarding duplicate entries (email). Re-deploying prisma seemed to be working in the terminal, but it actually was not.

The answer from @realAlexBarge put me in the right direction:

> "Also be careful that the new data model is actually deployed. If you have conflicts with the existing data it might be necessary to use the force flag to overwrite the existing schema anyways if so desired."

So what I did at the end:

1. stopped docker

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
```

2. deleted all tables from the database - probably "users" and "migration" is enough. As it seems the "migration" table keeps track of your scheema
3. restarted docker

```
docker-compose up -d
```

4. re-deployed prisma

```
prisma deploy
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply append the @unique directive to the email field of the user type to mark the field as unique. E.g.:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  name: String!
}
```

This will ensure that no two records will have the same email (other than null) as described in more detail in the prisma documentation:

> Setting the unique constraint makes sure that two records of the model
>   in question cannot have the same value for a certain field. The only
>   exception is the null value, meaning that multiple records can have
>   the value null without violating the constraint. Unique fields have a
>   unique index applied in the underlying database.

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/datamodel-and-migrations/datamodel-POSTGRES-knum/#unique

It's important however that you deploy the new data model. Only after deploying your data schema via the prisma CLI the database will consider the unique constraint for new and existing entries. Given that you configured your prisma.yml simply run:

```
$ prisma deploy
```

Also be careful that the new data model is actually deployed. If you have conflicts with the existing data it might be necessary to use the force flag to overwrite the existing schema anyways if so desired.

See: https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-cli-and-configuration/cli-command-reference/prisma-deploy-xcv9/

Comment: The links here don't seem to work anymore.